# what safari/firefox setting would stop testcafe setup working that works fine with Chrome?

Tags: testcafe

I'm using Testcafe and started with Chrome as my test browser.
Once I had a working setup I tried it on Safari and then Firefox.

On Chrome my tests are found and all succeed.
On Safari and Firefox the tests run but all fail.

My config file is:

```
module.exports = {
    appInitDelay: 10000,
    concurrency: 1,
    browsers: ["firefox", "safari"],
    hostname: "localhost",
    src: "tests/",
    pageRequestTimeout: 10000,
    quarantineMode: true,
    retryTestPages: true,
}
```

I've tried versions with/without `appInitDelay`, `concurrecy`, `hostname`, `pageRequestTimeout`, `quarantineMode`, and `retryTestages`.

I've also tried command-line arguments too with no difference in behaviour.

When a test fails, Testcafe reports:

```
Failed to load the page at "http://localhost:3000/".
Increase the value of the "pageRequestTimeout" variable, enable the
"retryTestPages" option, or use quarantine mode to perform
additional attempts to execute this test.
You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at
"https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".
      
Error details:
Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at
"http://localhost:3000/".
```

I have tried another solution: disabling all uses of `TestCafe Browser Tools` in `System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Automation` but on rerunning `testcafe` I am not prompted to renable those uses.

For Safari `v16.6` I've enabled `Allow remote automation`. For Firefox, I've used a clean install `v115`. The clue is that Chrome `v115` works.

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe 3.0.0 tests are run in the native automation mode for Chrome via CDP (chrome debug protocol). This mode runs tests in a more stable and correct way. Safari and Firefox don't have CDP. Therefore, it's impossible to run tests in the same way as in Chrome.

Your issue looks like a bug. Please [create a new issue in the TestCafe repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&projects=&template=bug_report.yaml) and share [a simple sample](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&projects=&template=bug_report.yaml).

Comment: thanks, Alexey; I'll add a new issue